# Deleting a dependency / primary key (id) - Not working Ruby on Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, dependencies, associations

So I have two tables, "houses" and "landowners". "houses" has a column named "landowner_id", such that on the site when someone adds a house they can optionally specify the owner_id. Thus,

```
class House < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :landowner
```

and

```
class LandOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses, dependent: :nullify
```

I am using the dependent: :nullify above in order to have my tables set up in such a way that when I delete an owner record that I have previously added, it then deletes the landowner_id from any houses that have the same landowner_id as the id of the owner that was deleted. However, it won't delete the landowner_id record.

Comment: please read the question once again and edit it appropriately. I  am confused with `owner_id` , `owner` word. also here, it has extra comma `has_many :houses, , dependent: :nullify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `dependent: :destroy`

```
class LandOwner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :houses, dependent: :destroy
```

Then you can do `@landowner.destroy`,which would delete all the houses that are associated with that landowner.

From the [Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html), `:nullify` causes the foreign keys to be set to NULL.While `:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.

Comment: I was originally using dependent: :destroy and it doesn't work. I have switched back to dependent: :destroy to double check, but not working...would I need to add anything somewhere else?

Comment: Is that a typo in your house model `belongs_to :owner`? It should be `belongs_to :landowner`

Comment: @modulus `dependent: :destroy` should work.I didn't see any reason why it is not working for you.Did you got any error?

Comment: No errors - would I need to add something like: `add_index` ?